# Drupal 6 "Machine Tags"

Tags: taxonomy-terms

We would like to hide accross our Drupal site all but certain types of nodes (to give you a more concrete idea: we're running a music blog and would like to have all reviews and interviews of non-female artists hidden for international women's day).

My idea was to add a new tag, "woman2013", that describes whether the node is to be featured or not, and then make sure that all our views filter all our nodes on this tag.

I will go over the templates and write PHP code that skips the display of the "woman2013" tag.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a machine tag. There seems to be no option however in Drupal (6) to do this.

What would be an alternative approach to achieve this result?

Comment: The [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module might be another option.

Comment: do you need to hide the tags from the public?

Comment: preferably the tags are hidden, yes.